# Failed to establish an invariant requiring the knowledge of the content of an array

Tags: frama-c

I try to use Frama-C to prove the invariant below. With the precondition that the array clean has at least one "true" in the first half, the loop should terminate before the last iteration and hence i will never be increased to BLOCK_NUM (=1000). However, Frama-C seems to ignore the content of clean and failed to establish the loop invariant. Does anyone know how to fix this proof?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define  BLOCK_NUM       1000

bool clean[BLOCK_NUM] ;  // clean bit for physical block; phy block ID -> bool

/*@
    requires \exists integer j; 0 <= j < BLOCK_NUM/2 ==> clean[j] == true;
*/
void test(){
        int i = 0;
        /*@
            loop assigns i;
            loop invariant 0 <= i < BLOCK_NUM;
        */
        while( i < BLOCK_NUM && clean[i] == false ){
            i += 1;
        }
}
```

I also tried a different version adding more information to the invariant

```c
void test(){
        int i = 0;
        /*@
            loop assigns i;
            loop invariant 0 <= i < BLOCK_NUM &&  
              \exists integer j; i <= j < BLOCK_NUM/2 ==> clean[j] == true;
        */
        while( i < BLOCK_NUM && clean[i] == false ){
            i += 1;
        }
        //@ assert 0 <= i < BLOCK_NUM;
}
```

This translates to the following proof condition.

```
Goal Invariant (preserved):
Assume {
  Type: is_sint32(i@L4) /\ is_sint32(1 + i@L4).
  [...]
  Stmt { L4:  }
  (* Invariant *)
  Have: (0 <= i@L4) /\ (i@L4 <= 999) /\
      (((i@L4 <= i_3) -> ((i_3 <= 499) -> (clean@L1[i_3] = 1)))).
  (* Then *)
  Have: clean@L1[i@L4] = 0.
}
Prove: ((-1) <= i@L4) /\ (i@L4 <= 998) /\
    (exists i_4 : Z. ((i@L4 < i_4) -> ((i_4 <= 499) -> (clean@L1[i_4] = 1)))).

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prover Alt-Ergo 2.4.1: Timeout (Qed:101ms) (10s) (cached).
```

But still all solvers (including Z3 and CVC4) fail to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your specification. First, your precondition is incorrect. What you want to say is that there exists a `j` such that `j` is between appropriate bounds **and** `clean[j] == true`, i.e.

```
requires \exists integer j; 0 <= j < BLOCK_NUM/2 && clean[j] == true;
```

More generally, and this can indeed be quite confusing at first, while a universal quantification generally goes along the lines of `\forall x; P(x) ==> Q(x)` (For any x such that P(x) holds, then Q(x) holds as well), existential quantification is usually something like `\exists x, P(x) && Q(x)`: if you use implication instead of conjunction in that case, then any x that does not satisfy P will be a witness for the existential formula.

The second point is that your loop invariant is too weak: you don't say anything about the values you've examined so far: with just the bounds on `i`, it is impossible to deduce that we will eventually check the value of the cell containing `true`. By adding as an invariant that we have examined all the cells before `i` (and found `false`, since otherwise we wouldn't be in the loop anymore), all the proofs can be completed automatically:

```
loop invariant all_false: \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> clean[j] == false;
```

Note that I've also added a name `all_false` to the new loop invariant. As your number of clauses grows, it is useful to give them explicit names, that will be used in Frama-C's output, so that you can quickly spot which proof obligation failed.

For what it's worth, here is the complete file (I removed the unnecessary includes)

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#define  BLOCK_NUM       1000

bool clean[BLOCK_NUM] ;  // clean bit for physical block; phy block ID -> bool

/*@
    requires \exists integer j; 0 <= j < BLOCK_NUM/2 && clean[j] == true;
*/
void test(){
        int i = 0;
        /*@
            loop assigns i;
            loop invariant all_false: \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> clean[j] == false;
            loop invariant 0 <= i < BLOCK_NUM;
        */
        while( i < BLOCK_NUM && clean[i] == false ){
            i += 1;
        }
}
```